# Does using the IN operator in MySql slow down performance?

Tags: mysql

My stored procedure is not finishing today like it was yesterday. It still says "Query is being executed..." at the bottom. The only thing I did differently today was add a few more comma separated values maybe twice as many. Will it take much longer for the query to finish now?

```
  DELETE FROM PRODUCTS
  WHERE STATUS IS NULL
  OR STATUS IN ('09','12','13','A1','C1','G1','G2','G3','H1','I1','J1','N1','S1','T1','T2','T3','T4')
```

Doesn't the query/procedure have to go through all the records again for each value?

Since I only want 3 values, C3, R1 and K1 would it be better to reverse it like.

```
  DELETE FROM PRODUCTS
  WHERE STATUS IS NULL
  OR STATUS NOT IN ('C3','K1','R1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding more choices to an `IN()` will have some effect on execution time.  How much effect is going to depend on whether that column is indexed.  If you need to improve this simple query, consider creating an index on `STATUS`.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Michaels comment (and for future reference) look up the `EXPLAIN` keyword. JoJo - it will help you to figure out what is happening behind the scenes.

The `NOT IN` is uaually slower than `IN` - as `IN` is in affect a whole bunch or `OR` expressions. With a good index on that column, the engine can simply pick them off one at a time.